# Add Solution to Source Control: Nothing happens

Tags: tfs

I've had my solution with the Beta TFS 2010 in source control, but then had to setup the server new and lost my source control stuff. Now I've setup the server again with the final version of TFS 2010.

I cleared all my bindings, so if you do "Change Source Control" the Server Binding column is empty. If I press Bind I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error message.

I can connect to the server and I have a "Team Project" created. But if I right-click on a project or the solution and choose "Add Solution to Source Control:" nothing happens at all. No error message, nothing...

What is wrong?

Update: I created a new solution from scratch and that can be added perfectly to TFS.

Comment: "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" is wrong. Sounds like a bad installation.

Comment: Bad installation of the client or the server? The server is a brand new installation and the client worked before...

Comment: Of the client. And the client "worked" with the beta if I understand you correctly. Whatever code is throwing the `NullReferenceException` needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: See below, emptying the  cache helped. Maybe there was Beta stuff in the cache or so. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try to clear TFS Cache see the following link:

http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2010/05/15/why-and-how-to-clear-tfs-client-cache/